# How to style the BlackoutDates from WPF calendar

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to style the the BlackoutDates of the WPF calendar. The default visualisation is a gray cross above the date numeral. How to only gray them out for example?

Comment: You need to dig into the massive [default `ControlTemplate` for the `Calendar` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468218(v=vs.110).aspx) and tweak it to your requirements.

Comment: @aDoubleSo create custom template for `CalendarDayButton` by changing  `Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle` which handles `BlackoutDay` visual state the way you want. Note that you'll need to handle other states as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go

```
<Calendar>
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsBlackedOut" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
    <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="24-June-2014" End="25-June-2014"/>
    </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
</Calendar>
```

I have specified a custom style for `CalendarDayButtonStyle` and in that style I defined a trigger on `IsBlackedOut` and set the `Background` to `LightGray`

result

[image: result]

you can choose to manipulate other properties as per your needs

**Remove existing blackout**

to remove existing blackout you have options of defining a custom template for the calendar day button, but the drawback is that you'll have to maintain it for every theme eg Luna, Classic etc

I am going to propose a solution which will help you utilize the existing template so no need to worry for such issues

I used Attached properties for same

class CalenderHelper

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class CalenderHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetIsBlackOutDisabled(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsBlackOutDisabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsBlackOutDisabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsBlackOutDisabledProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsBlackOutDisabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBlackOutDisabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsBlackOutDisabled", typeof(bool), typeof(CalenderHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBlackOutDisabledChanged));

        private static void OnIsBlackOutDisabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CalendarDayButton dayButton = d as CalendarDayButton;
            if (dayButton.IsLoaded)
            {
                SetBlackout(dayButton, (bool)e.NewValue);
            }
            else
            {
                dayButton.Loaded += (s, ee) =>
                {
                    SetBlackout(dayButton, (bool)e.NewValue);
                };
            }
        }

        static void SetBlackout(CalendarDayButton dayButton, bool collapsed)
        {
            ControlTemplate template = dayButton.Template;
            Path blackoutPath = template.FindName("Blackout", dayButton) as Path;
            if (collapsed)
                blackoutPath.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                blackoutPath.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a class `CalenderHelper` with an attached property `IsBlackOutDisabled` which will hide the blackout element in the existing template

xaml

```
<Calendar x:Name="cal" xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsBlackedOut" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="l:CalenderHelper.IsBlackOutDisabled" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
    <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="24-June-2014" End="25-June-2014"/>
    </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
</Calendar>
```

I have enabled my newly created property `l:CalenderHelper.IsBlackOutDisabled` in the trigger, which in turn will hide the default blackout visual

result

[image: result]

this approach make it flexible for many purpose, you may code it for other sophisticate functions which are not easily doable via simple xaml

Comment: *default visualisation is a gray cross above the date numeral. How to only gray them out for example?* I believe that this means, *How can I gray out the dates instead of having them crossed out*?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pure XAML, using Visual states :

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".35" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="ActiveStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Active" />
                            <VisualState Name="Inactive">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FFCBCBCB" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="DayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="RegularDay" />
                            <VisualState Name="Today">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FFFFFFFF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState Name="BlackoutDay">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".35" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="Blue"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="Silver"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="LightGray"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,1,5,1" TextElement.Foreground="Black"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    
</Style>
```

Solution lies in defining own ControlTemplate with It's visual states. Most important thing is inside **DayStates visual group** - VisualState with name **"BlackoutDay"**.

This way no attached properties is needed for overriding default blackout style, and all sorts of button colors for each control's state can be completely customized.